# Como posso formatar equações no Word 2013 de forma automática?

Tags: vba, microsoft-word

Utilizo o Microsoft Word como  editor de texto (Pacote office 2013). Construí documento com um documento com inúmeras equações fazendo o uso da ferramento *Microsoft Equation 3.0*. Contudo toda vez que salvo o documento, peço para atualizar os índices de figuras, ou abro o documento em outro máquina, algumas equações (e símbolos)  perdem a formatação que apliquei.

Com este contexto, gostaria de saber se existe alguma formam de reformatar (rotina) ou padronizar estas equações. De modo que, estas formações não se percam independentemente da operação que faça no/com documento.

Peço desculpas se estou fugindo do escopo do SO, mas fiquei curioso, pois outro dia encontrei uma [rotina](http://answers.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/forum/office_2010-word/formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-v%C3%A1rias-imagens-word/8521f49e-0eb7-4b12-9d4c-144ec23059f7) em VB que aumenta ou reduz o tamanho das imagens em lote, a qual, me quebrou uma baita galho.

Tentei essa esta questão em fóruns específicos da ferramenta, mas até então não obtive sucesso. Mas tendo em vista a pluralidade dos profissionais que acessam o SO, decidi buscar por uma dica, já que estou cansado de passar equação por equação/símbolo por símbolo, toda vez que preciso entregar um relatório.

PS: caso seja necessária mais alguma informação solicitem nos comentários, que assim possível eu respondo ou atualizo a questão.

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar LaTeX? A curva de aprendizagem é grande, mas a incomodação que se evita ao não usar o Word para escrever equações vale a pena (disclaimer: sou Matemático, portanto posso ter uma opinião viciada sobre este assunto).

Comment: Sim já, pretendo investir tempo nisso em breve, mas agora posso, então pensei em uma solução paliativa. De qual quer forma, obrigado pela potente dica!

Comment: Jean, para utilizar LaTeX você não vai precisar de tempo para aprender. Uma - duas horas no máximo. É muito simples, sem contar que existem ótimos sites exemplificando tudo o que você precisa.

Comment: Jean, você pode criar um [mcve] (um documento do Word de exemplo) em que você reproduza esse "problema"? Também poderia adicionar algumas imagens do "antes e depois". De que tipo de "formatação" você está falando? Tipo negrito? Pergunto porque **eu não consegui reproduzir** nenhum problema parecido por aqui no meu Word (Office 2010).

Comment: Btw, eu acho que a sua pergunta cabe no site por envolver VBA (que é programação). Mas o problema não está claro. E, aliás, como nota para o futuro, eu também sugiro que siga o conselho do colega @MarcusNunes. Depois que você aprende LaTeX nunca mais quer voltar a usar Word. :)

Comment: Grato pela sugestão @Luiz Vieira. Estou passando por problemas no momento, assim que conseguir vou construir o exemplo. *Em resumo um caso bem específico*, considere um símbolo (alfa) inserido no corpo do texto, formatado no ME 3.0 em tamanho de fonte 12 e estílo Texto; e este mesmo símbolo disposto em uma Tabela, com fonte 10 e estilo Matemático. Se editar uma ou outra, a formatação do elemento em edição recebera a ultima formação realizada. Entendo que isso talvez seja uma limitação do ME 3.0, mas há de se ter alguma de contornar esta inconveniência.Sim irei aprender LaTeX

Comment: Ah! Ok, então o seu problema **não tem nada a ver com equações**, mas sim com o uso de estilos (e você não havia mencionado isso na sua pergunta!!!). Estilos são o que o nome diz: uma definição de formatação **reutilizável**. Se você aplica um estilo num trecho qualquer de texto (não importa se é equação ou não!) e depois muda manualmente, o Word vai desconsiderar a atualização se você não aplicá-la ao estilo. Se você quer ter dois tipos de formatação distintas (para equações na tabela e fora dela), você deve criar dois estilos distintos!

Comment: E, sinto muito, mas a sua pergunta não faz parte do escopo do site. Ela já quase não fazia antes, agora certamente não faz. Eu só não voto pra fechar porque... porque eu não consigo, já que o sistema não deixa por ter uma recompensa ativa. Mas o seu problema é na verdade dificuldade de uso do Word. [Leia sobre estilos na documentação](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Personalizar-estilos-no-Word-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563).

Comment: Esta pergunta está envolvida em uma discussão no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329/n%c3%a3o-d%c3%a1-pra-fechar-pergunta-com-recompensa-ativa-por-que-mesmo

Comment: **O estilo do texto não esta ligado com o estilo da equação (Microsoft Equation 3.0)**, funcionam em paralelo. De qualquer forma obrigado pela considerações. Minha intenção era causar nenhum debate, e se caso for, eu mesmo fecho a questão.

Comment: Não importa se não esteja ligado. Se você usa estilos para a equação, você tem o mesmo problema. Sobre a pergunta, deixa ela aberta. Afinal, vc já gastou a recompensa mesmo. E discussões fazem parte de uma comunidade. :)

Comment: Não pela recompensa gasta, até por não me importo com isso. Mas sim pelo conhecimento. **Ressalto, o "Estilo" (Matriz, Vetor, Matemático, Variável) do objeto gerado pelo *Microsoft Equation 3.0*, neste caso específico, nada tem a ver com o ESTILO [https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Personalizar-estilos-no-Word-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563] do texto, não funcionam da mesma forma, então são problemas diferentes**. Concordo contigo @LuizVieira fazem parte e mais, agregam conhecimento. Assim que possível investirei tempo em LaTeX para contornar o problema Obrigado!

Comment: Eu entendi o que você disse. Você é que não entendeu o que eu disse. Eu *não estou dizendo que são a mesma função* do Word. O que eu disse é que se você usa estilos no Equation Editor, *lá também* você deve configurar as formatações diretamente nos estilos e usar estilos distintos para as variações.

Comment: Joia :) !!!  Estou em discussão na comunidade da Microsoft, verei o que eles dizem, e caso solucionem a questão comunico aqui também. Valeu!

Comment: Opa, por nada! Fico feliz de talvez ter ajudado de alguma forma. Boa sorte! :) P.S.: Saiba que [tag:latex] faz parte do escopo do site (é algo já discutido algumas vezes - o meu entendimento, e de alguns outros, é que trata-se sim de "programação", já que envolve a construção de documentos utilizando uma linguagem própria e muitas vezes até com decisões lógicas. Assim, você é bem vindo também a postar dúvidas a esse respeito, além de dúvidas de VBA. Mas, se preferir, tem também o [Tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

`LaTex` é uma solução padrão e muito difundida para o que você deseja.

Porém, a curto prazo, que tal gerar/capturar uma imagem da equação e inseri-la diretamente no seu documento ? Isso tornaria a fórmula um objeto de imagem e jamais perderia a formatação.

Outra alternativa é uma ferramenta on-line que converte `LaTex` para o formato do Word: http://engenharialivre.com/latex-para-word/

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! De que forma posso "gerar/capturar" cada equação/símbolo, existe uma opção disso no *Microsoft Equation 3.0*, ou seira algo mo copiar e colar espacial (imagem)?